# Does the RESTful Service exposed need to check for XSS Attacks

Tags: wcf, rest, wcf-security, wcf-rest

I have a RESTful WCF service that exposes a method that takes in an XElement as a parameter.

Now i want to know if i need to check the incoming message for XSS attacks first or does the framework handle it by default.

If i need to handle do i use the Microsoft XSS library to perform this operation on the XElement string that comes in from the request.

Comment: You need to be more specific when you say wcf rest service.  Wcf using webhttpbinding or web API?

Comment: Hi Darrel, Just wanted to know how does it differ if its WebHttpBinding or WebAPI.

Comment: They are two completely different libraries for building REST services.  Web API is the one done right ;-)

Comment: Hi Darrel, Sorry i might be silly to ask but how would you distinguish on how you are developing your RESTful services. I have implemented REST services in 2 types : 1. Using the WebHttpBinding 2. Using the MVC style i.e Routing mechanism i dont have any configuration here.

Comment: I use my own framework but am planning to migrate to web API at some point.  Web API integrates nicely with MVC, so that option may be worth exploring.

Comment: I did build some REST services using the Web API style that uses the MVC style. I did download the template to WCF REST service application that uses the web API style. But anyways i think for the question i raised i think i need to validate for XSS attacks irrespective of WebHttpbinding or Web API

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check the below link for further details

[REST Security](http://www.infoq.com/news/2010/03/REST_security)

REST does not have predefined security methods so developers define their own, and
Often, developers in a hurry to just get... services deployed don't treat them with the same level of diligence as they treat web applications.